# m2e pro keep ebay quantity

Tags: magento, m2e

Is there a way for m2e pro to keep certain qty of items available for each eBay Listing? For example, as long as we have stock in magento we would like the eBay listing to have qty=10.

If an item sell, we would like m2e pro to automatically revise it and put qty back to 10.

We are using a Price, Quantity and Format Policy with conditional QTY enabled, and Maximum Quantity to Be Listed = 10. But this doesn't seem to do the job. Items are purchased from the eBay listing, the qty available on eBay decreases, until the listing ends. We want to keep the listings alife and qty = 10 for as long as there is stock available in magento.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Perhaps it would be better to post this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your desired quantity in   "Price, Quantity and Format Policy". Instead of using product qty you can use custom value. If you want to set different value for each product use a custom attribute like "ebay_available_qty" and put values to it.

This is for m2epro verion 6.x.x . For older version do the same thing in selling format template in "
Quantity and Duration " section.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this way of doing it is that when your actual `magento` quantity goes below 10 or even to zero, `m2e` pro will still list 10 available and then you may have some upset customers if you can't fulfill the order.

Comment: I think that this could be more like a comment